# Draw string with chalk effect (cocoa/cocoa touch)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

is there good way to draw string with chalk effect? Can I draw a transparent string over a chalk texture image?

Comment: I feel it is a good question however. I find this question helpful.

Comment: I did search in Google, but I failed. Sometimes, ask some guru is pretty quick, right? But thanks for the reminder, I will try to figure it out before raising the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS:

1. Get a chalk texture image.
2. Create a colour using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chalkImage"]];`
3. Set this as the text colour for your label or text view or whatever.

For OSX:

1. Get a chalk texture image.
2. Create a colour using `[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"chalkImage"]];`
3. Set this as the text colour for your label or text view or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know UIColor and NSColor can be used in such way.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you use only latin letters, there is a great font called `Chalkduster` in MacOS and iOS.